# 2 almost identical "hello world" Flask apps, 1 works, 1 returns 404 Not Found

Tags: python, apache, flask

I am new to Flask (and these type of app frameworks) and am trying to set it up on a VPS.  I am running apache2 on Ubuntu 20.04, if that helps.

Following [this example](https://www.codementor.io/@abhishake/minimal-apache-configuration-for-deploying-a-flask-app-ubuntu-18-04-phu50a7ft), I managed to get the "Hello world" app running.  I then tried to get another example up and running just to see if I could.  The code and files are identical, outside of the paths, which go to the different files.  Even the permissions on all files have been opened up to everyone (bad practice, I know, just trying to get it to work)

From what I can tell, this app is odd in that the .py file tries to handle the "/" path with this line

```
@app.route("/")
```

despite the WSGIScriptAlias referencing "/testFlask".

```
WSGIScriptAlias /testFlask /home/user/ExampleFlask/ExampleFlask/my_flask_app.wsgi
```

But it works and if I change that line in the .py file to "/testFlask" instead of just "/", it also returns a 404 error.

For reference, the working /etc/apache2/sites-available/ExampleFlask.conf file contains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
         # Add machine's IP address (use ifconfig command)
         ServerName IP_ADDRESS_HERE
         # Give an alias to to start your website url with
         WSGIScriptAlias /testFlask /home/user/ExampleFlask/ExampleFlask/my_flask_app.wsgi
         <Directory /home/user/ExampleFlask/ExampleFlask/>
                        # set permissions as per apache2.conf file
                        Options FollowSymLinks
                        AllowOverride None
                        Require all granted
         </Directory>
         ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
         LogLevel warn
         CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

/home/user/ExampleFlask/ExampleFlask/my_flask_app.wsgi

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.6

import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user/ExampleFlask/ExampleFlask')
from my_flask_app import app as application
application.secret_key = 'BOB'
```

/home/user/ExampleFlask/ExampleFlask/my_flask_app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
        return "Hello world!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

The second app that fails is identical, but replace "ExampleFlask" with "NewFlask" in the paths and a different secret key.  Also the following line has a different alias

```
WSGIScriptAlias /newFlask /home/user/NewFlask/NewFlask/my_flask_app.wsgi
```

Lastly, if this helps, output from apache2ctl -S
Apache is running on localhost(but still displays externally), while the others on on my IP address

```
port 80 namevhost 127.0.0.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
port 80 namevhost IP_ADDRESS (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ExampleFlask.conf:1)
port 80 namevhost IP_ADDRESS (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/NewFlask.conf:1)
```

edit : I forgot to mention - nothing in the error log for the 404 errors.  All I see when I restart the server and attempt to reach the app -

```
[Thu Apr 01 17:35:14.234997 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 613:tid 140596752829504] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 01 17:35:14.235014 2021] [core:notice] [pid 613:tid 140596752829504] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: Apache should save errors in log file - `errors.log` - (see `ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log` in config) and you should check if there are some other information.

Comment: you should't use two servers with the same `ServerName`. Normally it should be used as page URL - ie. `ServerName stackoverflow.com` to define web server for adress `http://stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Not sure I understand the second comment, furas - conf file Servername in the conf file is currently just the IP address, not a URL.

Comment: as I remeber when you have the same value in two `ServerName` then Apache uses only first matching configuration. When browser connect to server then server checks request header `host` with all configs and it uses first matching config.

Comment: BTW: in every config you could use unique names for `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` (ie. `server1-access.log`, `server2-access.log` and then you will see which server was used for url used in web browser.